# Как и где можно загрузить libgdx для AIDE?

Tags: android, libgdx, aide

Как и где можно загрузить libgdx чтоб прям в архиве zip а в нем весь код библиотеки? Или есть другие способы загрузить libgdx в AIDE? Помогите, если есть такие же как я, повторяю это не Android Studio, ни Eclipse - это **AIDE**

Comment: спасибо за правку)

Comment: Так в AIDE сразу можно создать проект с libGDX. Зачем вам его отдельно загружать?

Comment: А загрузить можно тут https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html. Подключите gdx.jar, gdx-backend-android.jar и скопируйте libgdx.so в папку libs для нужных вам архитектур

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIDE не полностью поддерживает gradle:

> The full gradle build system is not yet supported though.

ист.: http://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_androidstudio.html

но есть примеры ридми как делать руками:

https://github.com/Deepscorn/libgdx-gradle-template/blob/master/README.md#aide

или вот еще http://deepscorn.blogspot.co.nz/2016/07/building-and-running-android-studio.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.